# SQL efficient complex filtering when id are in a list

Tags: sql

Sorry, I'm very novice in SQL and the title is probably not very clear, it's probably easier to explain with an example.

I have a table (see below) containing all the food item of a series of lunches.

```
---------------------------
| id | lunch_id | food_id |
---------------------------
|  1 |       11 |      21 |
|  2 |       11 |      22 |
|  3 |       11 |      23 |
|  4 |       12 |      21 |
|  5 |       12 |      24 |
|  6 |       12 |      25 |
|  7 |       13 |      21 |
|  8 |       13 |      23 |
|  9 |       13 |      26 |
```

I want to select all the `lunch_id` which contains a list of specific food items.

E.g. I want all the `lunch_id` which contains the `food_id` 21 **AND** 23, in this example the result is 11 and 13.

I can do it with a series of SQL statements, but I suspect there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the `lunch_id` and take only those groups having **both** `food_id`s.

```
select lunch_id
from your_table
where food_id in (21,23)
group by lunch_id
having count(distinct food_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use exists

```
   select t1.* from table_name t1
   where exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.lunch_id =t2.lunch_id 
                                        and t2.food_id in (21,23
                        having count(*)=2
                 )
```